# Android studio - How to save data selected on previous activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is a snippet of my code. The `Textview` acts as buttons and have `Onclicklistner` on them. When cpu1000 `Textview` is clicked it leads to the `cpu_g1000` class for which the code is shown below.

```
public class Game_1000 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private TextView cpu1000, mobo1000;

TextView cpu, mobo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_1000);

    cpu1000 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.proName_G1);
    mobo1000 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.moboName_G1);

    cpu1000.setOnClickListener(this);
    mobo1000.setOnClickListener(this);

    cpu = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.proNameG1000);
    cpu.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("Processor"));

    mobo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.moboNameG1000);
    mobo.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("Motherboard"));
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v == cpu1000) {
        opencpu_g1000();
    }
    else if (v == mobo1000) {
        openmobo_g1000();
    }
}

public void opencpu_g1000() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, cpu_g1000.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void openmobo_g1000() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, mobo_g1000.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

In this class, there are radio buttons. The users choose one of the choices and the choice is changed to strings. The strings are sent back to `Game_1000` class. The string then gets substituted with **"Choose a processor"** to show the new choice. The issue I am having is when I choose a motherboard the processor choice is reverted back to **"Choose a processor"** and the motherboard choice shows. I need both to show at the same time.

```
public class cpu_g1000 extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button_save;
RadioGroup rG;
TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cpu_g1000);

    button_save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Save_G1_cpu);
    rG = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.cpu_RadioGrp);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.proNameG1000);

    button_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            int selected_cpu = rG.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            RadioButton selectedRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selected_cpu);

            String radioValue = selectedRadioButton.getText().toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent(cpu_g1000.this, Game_1000.class);
            intent.putExtra("Processor", radioValue);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    });
}
```

**Processor is chosen:**

[image: Processor is chosen]

**Motherboard is chosen:**

[image: Motherboard is chosen]

**Example of choices:**

[image: Example of choices]

The previous choice are not recored and when a new choice is made the previous choice reverts back to "Please choose a processor" but I need both of the information to show. In my original code, I have more than just 2 choices but I shortened it to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Start your second (Selection) activity for result by calling `startActivityForResult(...)` and then when user completes the interaction set your selected data in an `Intent` and pass that intent to method with desired result `setResult(...)` then call finish on second activity.

After finishing the second activity you will receive intent data in `onActivityResult(...)` method of first activity, extract that data from intent and then show it to user.

[More Description](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

[Example](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Shared Preference](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html). Here's a good [tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/).

Comment: This is not a good approach for this kind of functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario what you have to do is save Processor and Motherboard selection result or send data form one Activity to another Activity. As after processor selection you are returning to `Game_1000` Activity you can use [startActivityForResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29). This method send back the result to calling Activity via Intent. Thats means if you call `cpu_g1000` Activity from `Game_1000` Activity and after selecting Processor you can send back the result to `Game_1000` Activity.  `Game_1000` Activity will get the result in [`onActivityResult`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)) method.

**Example:**

Start `cpu_g1000` Activity  with [startActivityForResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) from `Game_1000` Activity.

```
public void opencpu_g1000() {
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, cpu_g1000.class);
  startActivityForResult(intent, PROCESSOR_SELECTION_CODE);
}
```

In `cpu_g1000` Activity set the result to intent and send back to `Game_1000` Activity

```
    button_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        int selected_cpu = rG.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        RadioButton selectedRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selected_cpu);

        String radioValue = selectedRadioButton.getText().toString();

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
         // TODO Add data to send back
        resultIntent.putExtra("ProcessorSelection", radioValue); 
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
        // finishing this activity
        finish();

    }

});
```

In `Game_1000` Activity get the value sent form `cpu_g1000` Activity by overriding [`onActivityResult`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)) method.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

  switch(requestCode) {
    case (PROCESSOR_SELECTION_CODE) : {
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        // TODO Extract the data returned from the child Activity.
        String radioValue = data.getStringExtra("ProcessorSelection");
        // save the result value and update UI 
      }
      break;
    } 
 }
}
```

For `mobo_g1000` Activity use same procedure to get the result back in `Game_1000` Activity. Start `mobo_g1000` Activity with [startActivityForResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) and get the value in `Game_1000` Activity's [`onActivityResult`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)) method. You have to add another `case` in [`onActivityResult`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)) method for `mobo_g1000` Activity.

Check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) and [this](http://www.dummies.com/web-design-development/mobile-apps/how-to-get-results-back-from-an-activity-in-your-android-app/) link for better understanding how this work.

Comment: Thank you for help but when I try to use the code - "PROCESSOR_SELECTION_CODE" and "Activity".RESULT_OK says Cannot resolve symbol.

Comment: declare  `PROCESSOR_SELECTION_CODE` as a `int` variable and `RESULT_OK` in defined in `Activity` class. see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#RESULT_OK here

Comment: I followed your guide and did it but when i run the application the selected processor never came through from the cpu_g1000 to Game_1000.