# IF statement on list view

Tags: java, android

Could someone help me change my IF statement to take in the detail that is inside the list view rather than the position of the listview? The list view will display three details which can be seen in the image below.

```
listViewSaves.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (position == 0) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Game_500.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            }
            if (position == 1) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Game_1000.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            }
            if (position == 2) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your toast message3.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Check below image for an example of the list view

[image: An example of the list view]

Check the below image for how the list view is populated

[image: How the list view is populated]

I want the listview to open up their own activity. For example IF the list view shows (Gaming) and (Under 500) - open `Game_500.class`.

If the list view has (Gaming) and (Under 1000) -open `Game_1000.class`.

The list view is populated by asking the users to select from 2 choices. Type of system - **Gaming** or **Personal Use** and the price of the system - **Under 500** or **Under 1000**.

Comment: Use the ListView's data-list as a global field and get the specific object from this data-list using the index provided in the onItemClick callback.

Comment: How you populating list view ?

Comment: An edit text and two spinners which are = Type of system - Gaming or personal use and the price of the system - Under 500 or under 1000.

Comment: did you use any `pojo` class for Listview  Adapter

Comment: I haven't used any complex stuff partly because I don't know how to but when the user inputs the data it goes into firebase database and gets retrieved into the list view onto the app.

Comment: ok post your ListViewAdapter code so that in can help you with your existing code.

Comment: I didn't know which one to put so I put the codes that are connected to it. I'm sorry but thank you very much for helping this far tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code for `ListView` `setOnItemClickListener`. Here you have to take `RigSaves` object from List with position and check if it meet your criteria.

```
listViewSaves.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

        RigSaves rigSaves = savesList.get(position);

         // Gaming option 
        if( rigSaves.getRigType().equals("Gaming") && rigSaves.getRigPrice().equals("Under 500") ){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Game_500.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
        }

        if( rigSaves.getRigType().equals("Gaming") && rigSaves.getRigPrice().equals("Under 1000") ){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Game_1000.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
        }

        // personal option 
        if( rigSaves.getRigType().equals("Personal Use") && rigSaves.getRigPrice().equals("Under 500") ){
          // start activity you want to start
        }

        if( rigSaves.getRigType().equals("Personal Use") && rigSaves.getRigPrice().equals("Under 1000") ){
           // start activity you want to start
        }

    }
});
```

Hope it helps you. And let me know if you faced any problem

Comment: You are a lifesaver! Thank you soo much I've been looking for tutorials and trying to find ways to work out how to do this for days!  I appreciate it greatly.

Comment: Glad to know that it helps you. Thanks.

Comment: Hey, I ran into some issue with another bit of my code could you possibly help me again? I'm really sorry to bother you and if you are busy please free to ignore. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49056785/android-studio-how-to-save-data-selected-on-previous-activity

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :

When calling `Intent`, you should use the class's name as string with package name. So if your class is called `Game_1000` and is in the package mypackage.tests, then you should use:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Class.forName("mypackage.tests.Game_1000"));
MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```